# PHP- merge two xml attribute withou duplicated

Tags: php, xml, merge, duplicates

I have two xmls like this
xml1:

```
 <Title>Sea Change</Title>
    <thirdParty_ID></thirdParty_ID>
    <Animation_Indicator>N</Animation_Indicator>
    <Blackout_Indicator>N</Blackout_Indicator>
<SD_Purchase_Zoe></SD_Purchase_Zoe>
    <SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe></SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
    <SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe></SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe>
    <SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe></SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
<HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>2012-04-01</HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
    <HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe>2013-04-01</HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe>
    <HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>2012-04-01</HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
```

xml2:

```
<Asset_Record>
    <Title>Sea Change</Title>
    <thirdParty_ID></thirdParty_ID>
    <Animation_Indicator>N</Animation_Indicator>
    <Blackout_Indicator>N</Blackout_Indicator>
<SD_Purchase_Zoe>Y</SD_Purchase_Zoe>
    <SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>2012-04-01</SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
    <SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe>2013-04-01</SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe>
    <SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>2012-04-01</SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
<HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe></HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
    <HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe></HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe>
    <HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe></HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
```

I would like to merge xml1 and xml2 and output like

```
<Title>Sea Change</Title>
    <thirdParty_ID></thirdParty_ID>
    <Animation_Indicator>N</Animation_Indicator>
    <Blackout_Indicator>N</Blackout_Indicator>
<SD_Purchase_Zoe>Y</SD_Purchase_Zoe>
    <SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>2012-04-01</SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
    <SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe>2013-04-01</SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe>
    <SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>2012-04-01</SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
    <SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe></SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
<HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>2012-04-01</HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
    <HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe>2013-04-01</HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe>
    <HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>2012-04-01</HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
```

First I need to check are these two xmls have the same titles, if they have the same titles and merge them, and merge all the values if it is possible to find from any of them.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I write somethink like this:

```
$x1 = <<<XML
<xml>
<Title>Sea Change</Title>
<thirdParty_ID></thirdParty_ID>
<Animation_Indicator>N</Animation_Indicator>
<Blackout_Indicator>N</Blackout_Indicator>
<SD_Purchase_Zoe></SD_Purchase_Zoe>
<SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe></SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
<SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe></SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe>
<SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe></SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
<HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>2012-04-01</HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
<HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe>2013-04-01</HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe>
<HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>2012-04-01</HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
</xml>
XML;

$x2 = <<<XML
<xml>
<Title>Sea Change</Title>
<thirdParty_ID></thirdParty_ID>
<Animation_Indicator>N</Animation_Indicator>
<Blackout_Indicator>N</Blackout_Indicator>
<SD_Purchase_Zoe>Y</SD_Purchase_Zoe>
<SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>2012-04-01</SD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
<SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe>2013-04-01</SD_Purchase_Window_End_Zoe>
<SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>2012-04-01</SD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
<HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe></HD_Licensing_Window_start_Zoe>
<HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe></HD_Licensing_Window_end_Zoe>
<HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe></HD_Purchase_Window_Start_Zoe>
</xml>
XML;

$oXML1 = new SimpleXMLElement($x1);
$oXML2 = new SimpleXMLElement($x2);

$oOutput = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml></xml>');

foreach ( $oXML1 as $key => $value )
{
    if ( empty($value[0]) )
        $oOutput->addChild($key, $oXML2->{$key}[0]);
    else
        $oOutput->addChild($key, $value[0]);
}

print_r($oOutput->asXML());
```